# Change input text based on radio button click in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, label, external

This is my code:

```
<div id="title">
    <label class="" id="title-text" for="title">Hello World</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc-title" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div id="title-select">
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-0" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="title-format-0">Title 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-1" value="1"> <label for="title-format-1">Title 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-2" value="2"> <label for="title-format-2">Title 3</label>
</div>
```

What i need is,

1. when a radio item is clicked, it should display the respective title. Say when radio button 2 is clicked, "Title 2" should get updated for label and input elements above.
2. This needs to be done in an EXTERNAL JS FILE!
3. The 2 DIV blocks mentioned above are actually placed in separate PHP files and are heavily cascaded. So need a pure JS fix.

Currently what i have in my external file is this (ext file is getting called properly):

```
$('input[name=title_format]').click(function()  {
    $('input[name=doc-title]').value('Title changed to 2');
};
```

Ofcourse this code seems completely useless.
Hope somebody helps me here.

PS: I am an absolute noob in js/jquery so please excuse if this is a simple fix.
I would prefer simple javascript fix for this if possible.
Else JQuery, which i understand is by including jquery-2.1.1.min.js file before my js file.

Answer (score 3):

try this:
html:

```
<div id="title">
        <label class="" id="title-text" for="title">Hello World</label>
        <input type="text" name="doc-title" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div id="title-select">
        <input type="radio" name="title_format" value="title3" onclick="changeTheText(this.value);" class="title-format" id="title-format-0" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="title-format-0">Title 1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="title_format" value="title3" onclick="changeTheText(this.value);" class="title-format" id="title-format-1" value="1"> <label for="title-format-1">Title 2</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="title_format" value="title3" onclick="changeTheText(this.value);" class="title-format" id="title-format-2" value="2"> <label for="title-format-2">Title 3</label>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
function changeTheText(theValue)
{
  document.getElementById('title').value = theValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f9ztmw2z/1/)**

You forgot to close the click function.
Also make a document ready function. Or else it does not know which element its about.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=title_format]').click(function()  {
        $('[name=doc-title]').val('Title changed to '+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

EDIT: now changes the input text to the value of the radio button.

Comment: Good find ... missed that part.

Comment: but the code aint working... becasue my code is spread across multiple php files and the code mentioned above is heavily cascaded and placed in multiple files, but the 2 DIV codeblocks remain same. so does this mean that i need a full pageload or something to check? sorry to bother. thanks again for the fix.

Comment: Why are all codes in different pages? Why not make one page? Are the input and the radio buttons in a iframe? Also try to insert the external JS script in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the files are loading correctly, try ...

Change `.value` to `.val`

Answer (score 0):

here is your html code(just added jquery cdn and external JS file)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jack.js"></script>

<div id="title">
    <label class="" id="title-text" for="title">Hello World</label>
    <input type="text" name="doc-title" value="" id="title" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div id="title-select">
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-0" value="0" checked="checked"><label for="title-format-0">Title 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-1" value="1"> <label for="title-format-1">Title 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="title_format" class="title-format" id="title-format-2" value="2"> <label for="title-format-2">Title 3</label>
</div>
```

and your external javascript code jack.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:radio[name=title_format]").click(function() {

        var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
        var value = $("label[for='"+idVal+"']").text();

        $('input[name=doc-title]').val(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The 2 DIV blocks are placed in multiple files and are heavily cascaded. Would this become an issue with this codefix? Because it isnt working for me so am wondering. Thanks again..

Comment: hmmm then you need to work with ID and Class, if i look your whole code then get some idea about that

Comment: so for ID it is "input:radio[ID=title-format-1]" and similar? thanks for replying.. will try.

Answer (score 0):

Is correct to use `.val`.

In your example there is an error at the end JS, you miss a `)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/m05rkdsa/

Answer (score 0):

> try this
>
> js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#title-select .title-format').click(function()  {
   var title=$(this).next().text();
   $('#title :input').val(title);
});
})
```

> html script registration

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-file.js"></script>
```